# A file as input in C

Tags: c, linux, input

I need to input a file in a c program for Linux

```
a.out < inputfile
```

The problem is that i don't know how to receive a file

it can't be like:

```
FILE *fp;
char filename[100];
fopen = (fp,"r");
...
```

I need as input the file, no the name.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can read it by reading `stdin`.

Comment: @wildplasser Wouldn't just use argc, argv work better?

Comment: Ok sorry, got it, Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stdin as your file pointer. It's already declared and open You don't need an fopen